# Spans jumping around on resize and/or zoom

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

I'm at a loss - my Javascript is terrible and I'm trying to show some span based panels that hold some tables. The panels are simply left-side and right-side panels (you select something on the left - you see something on the right). 
I need to be using spans as I've got Ajax repopulating them regularly. I also need to use the span with the id ResizableListTableDiv as it's necessary whilst using the great fxHeader javascript found at www.jaimon.co.uk (I've embedded the code to assist pulling the samples in) [note - the version I'm using doesn't seem to exactly match the version on jaimon.co.uk now]

My panels work to a point but I see problems :-

1) when the page zoom goes below 80%, or

2) when I resize the window, or

3) when I zoom in and out.

(the main problem being that the the right side panel flips over to under the other one on these events).

Note, I've only focused on IE so far - tips on how to make this any browser would be good too.

PS. Do I need to be doing this with Javascript or am I missing something and html should be doing it for me?

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
/*
 *  @Author Jaimon Mathew www.jaimon.co.uk
 *  Please see http://jaimonmathew.wordpress.com/2010/03/19/making-scrollable-tables-with-fixed-headers-updated-2/
*/
(function() {
    var flag=false;
    var tbl=new Array();
    this.ge$=function(d) {return document.getElementById(d);};
    this.scrollHeader = function(evt) {
        if(flag) {
            return;
        }
        var e=evt?evt:window.event;
        var t=e.target?e.target:e.srcElement;
    if (t.nodeType == 3) {
            t = t.parentNode;
        }
        var tid=t.id.replace(':scroller','');
        var fh=ge$(tid+':scroller:fx');
        var sd=ge$(tid+':scroller');
        fh.style.left=(0-sd.scrollLeft)+'px';
        var cf=ge$(tid+'_CFB');
        if(cf) {
            var dmt=parseInt(cf.getAttribute('dmt'));
            cf.style.marginTop=(0-(sd.scrollTop+dmt))+'px';
        }
    };
    function gbw() {
        return document.body.offsetWidth?document.body.offsetWidth:window.innerWidth;
    }
    function addScrollerDivs(tid,noOfCols) {
        if(ge$(tid+':scroller')) {
            return;
        }
        var tb=ge$(tid);
        var tb2=tb.parentNode;
        var ns=tb.nextSibling;
        var sd=document.createElement("div");
        sd.id=tid+':scroller';
        sd.style.cssText = 'height:auto;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:auto;width:auto;';
        sd.onscroll=scrollHeader;
        sd.appendChild(tb);
        var sd2=document.createElement("div");
        sd2.id=tid+':scroller:fx:OuterDiv';
        sd2.style.cssText='position:relative;width:auto;overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;padding:0px;margin:0px;';

        sd2.innerHTML='<div id="' + tid + ':scroller:fx" style="text-align:left;position:relative;width:9999px;padding:0px;margin-left:0px;"><font size="3" color="red">Please wait while loading the table..</font></div>';
        var fc=null;
        if(noOfCols > 0) {
            fc=document.createElement("div");
            fc.id=tid+':scroller:fxcol';
            fc.style.cssText='width:0px;height:auto;display:block;float:left;overflow:hidden;';
            fc.innerHTML = "<div id='" + tid +":scroller:fxCH' style='width:100%;overflow:hidden;'>&nbsp;</div><div id='" + tid +":scroller:fxCB' style='width:100%;overflow:hidden;'>&nbsp;</div>";
        }
        if(ns) {
            if(fc) tb2.insertBefore(fc, ns);
            tb2.insertBefore(sd2, ns);
            tb2.insertBefore(sd, ns);
        }else {
            if(fc) tb2.appendChild(fc);
            tb2.appendChild(sd2);
            tb2.appendChild(sd);
        }
    }

    this.fxheader = function() {
        if(flag) {return;}
        flag=true;
        var perUsed=false;
        for(var i=0;i<tbl.length;i++) {
            var tbDiv=ge$(tbl[i].tid);

            var w=tbl[i].swidth+'';
            if(w.indexOf('%')>=0) {
                perUsed=true;
                var ttt=ge$(tbl[i].tid+':scroller:fx');
                ttt.style.width='0px';
                var twi=parseInt(w);
                w=(gbw()*twi/100);
                ttt.style.width='9999px';
            }
            //if ie6/7 then allow for 18px scrollbar area
            tbDiv.style.width=(parseInt(w-18))+'px';
            var fh=ge$(tbl[i].tid + ':scroller:fx');
            fh.style.marginLeft='0px';
            fh.style.display='';
            var cn=fh.childNodes;
            var j;
            for(j=0;j<cn.length;j++) {
                fh.removeChild(cn[j]);
            }
            var t=tbDiv.cloneNode(false);
            t.id=tbl[i].tid+'__cN';
            if(document.all) {
                t.style.width=tbDiv.offsetWidth+'px';
            }else {
                t.style.width='auto';
            }
            t.style.marginTop='0px';
            t.style.marginLeft='0px';
            var th=document.createElement("thead");
            th.style.padding='0px';
            th.style.margin='0px';
            for(j=0;j<tbl[i].noOfRows;j++) {
                var r=tbDiv.rows[j].cloneNode(true);
                th.appendChild(r);
            }
            t.appendChild(th);
            fh.appendChild(t);
            var t2;
            if(tbl[i].noOfCols > 0) {
                t2=t.cloneNode(true);
                t2.id=tbl[i].tid + '_CFH';
            }
            //adjusting widths
            var tHeight=0;
            for(j=0;j<tbl[i].noOfRows;j++) {
                //var c=ge$(tbl[i].tid+'__cN').rows[j].cells;
                var c=t.rows[j].cells;
                var c2;
                var oc=tbDiv.rows[j].cells;
                var q;
                if(t2) {
                    c2=t2.rows[j].cells;
                    for(q=0;q<c.length;q++) {
                        c[q].style.width=c2[q].style.width=(oc[q].offsetWidth-3) + 'px';
                    }
                }else {
                    for(q=0;q<c.length;q++) {
                        c[q].style.width=(oc[q].offsetWidth-7) + 'px';
                    }
                }
                tHeight+=tbDiv.rows[j].offsetHeight;
            }
            tbDiv.style.marginTop = "-" + tHeight + "px";
            var h=tbl[i].sheight;
            if(tbDiv.offsetHeight < h) {
                h=tbDiv.offsetHeight+18;
            }
            var cw=0;
            //Column freezing
            if(tbl[i].noOfCols > 0) {
                for(j=0;j<tbl[i].noOfCols;j++) {
                    cw+=tbDiv.rows[0].cells[j].offsetWidth;
                }

                tbDiv.style.marginLeft = "-" + cw + "px";
                tbDiv.style.display='block';
                fh.style.marginLeft = "-" + cw + "px";
                var fxcol=ge$(tbl[i].tid+':scroller:fxcol').style;
                fxcol.width=(cw)+'px';
                var fxCH=ge$(tbl[i].tid+':scroller:fxCH');
                var fxCB=ge$(tbl[i].tid+':scroller:fxCB');
                fxCH.innerHTML='';
                fxCB.innerHTML='';
                fxCH.appendChild(t2);
                fxCH.style.height=tHeight+'px';
                fxCB.style.height=(h-tHeight)+'px';
                var t3=tbDiv.cloneNode(true);
                t3.id=tbl[i].tid + '_CFB';
                t3.style.marginLeft = "0px";
                t3.setAttribute('dmt', tHeight);
                fxCB.appendChild(t3);
            }
            w=(parseInt(w)-cw)+'px';
            //alert(i+') '+tbl[i].tid+'...'+h+'-'+tHeight); .. problems occur when h-tHeight go negative
            ge$(tbl[i].tid+':scroller').style.height=(h-tHeight) + 'px';
            ge$(tbl[i].tid+':scroller').style.width=w;
            ge$(tbl[i].tid+':scroller:fx:OuterDiv').style.height=tHeight + 'px';
            ge$(tbl[i].tid+':scroller:fx:OuterDiv').style.width=w;
        }
        //if(perUsed) {
            window.onresize=fxheader;
        //}
        flag=false;
    };

    this.reInit = function() {
        for(t=0; t<tbl.length;t++) {
            var _tid0=tbl[t].tid;
            var _tid1=tbl[t].tid+":scroller";
            var _tid2=tbl[t].tid+":scroller:fx:OuterDiv";
            var sheight;
            var o=document.getElementById(_tid1);
            r=o.offsetTop; 
            while(o=o.offsetParent)r+=o.offsetTop;
            t2=r;

            var o2=document.getElementById(_tid1);
            r=o2.offsetLeft; 
            while(o2=o2.offsetParent)r+=o2.offsetLeft; 
            var l2=r+35;

            var htmlwidth = document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth;
            var htmlheight = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;

            var d=document;
            var windowwidth = window.innerWidth;
            var windowheight = window.innerHeight;
            if (typeof window.innerWidth!='undefined') {
                windowwidth = window.innerWidth;
                windowheight = window.innerHeight;
            } else {
                 if (d.documentElement &&
                 typeof d.documentElement.clientWidth!='undefined' &&
                 d.documentElement.clientWidth!=0) {
                     windowwidth = d.documentElement.clientWidth;
                     windowheight = d.documentElement.clientHeight;
                 } else {
                     if (d.body &&
                     typeof d.body.clientWidth!='undefined') {
                         windowwidth = d.body.clientWidth;
                         windowheight = d.body.clientHeight;
                     }
                 }
            }

            if ( htmlheight < windowheight ) {
                document.body.height = windowheight;
                if ( windowheight>t2) {
                    sheight=(windowheight-t2);
                }
                else {
                    sheight=10;
                }
            } 
            else { 
                document.body.height = htmlheight;
                if ( htmlheight>t2) {
                    sheight= (htmlheight-t2-50);
                }
                else {
                    sheight=10;
                }
            } 
            if ( sheight > 200 ) {
                tbl[t].sheight=sheight;
            }

            var o2=document.getElementById(_tid0);
            var o3=document.getElementById(_tid1);
            var o4=document.getElementById(_tid2);
            if ( htmlwidth < windowwidth ) { 
                document.body.width = windowwidth + "px";
                //o2.style.width = (windowwidth-l2) + "px";
                o3.style.width = (windowwidth-l2) + "px";
                if ( o4 != null ) {
                    o4.style.width = o3.style.width;
                }
                //ResizableListTableBodyDiv2.style.width = (windowwidth-l2) + "px";
            } 
            else { 

                document.body.width = htmlwidth + "px"; 
                //o2.style.width = (htmlwidth-l2) + "px";
                o3.style.width = (htmlwidth-l2-25) + "px";
                if ( o4 != null ) {
                    o4.style.width = o3.style.width;
                }
                //ResizableListTableBodyDiv2.style.width = (htmlwidth-l2) + "px";
            }
        }
    };
    this.fxheaderInit = function(_tid,_sheight,_noOfRows,_noOfCols) {
        var tb = new Object();
        var td=ge$(_tid);
        tb.tid=_tid;
        tb.sheight=_sheight;
        if ( _sheight == 0 ) {

            var o=document.getElementById(_tid),r=o.offsetTop; 
               while(o=o.offsetParent)r+=o.offsetTop; 
               t2=r+30;

            var htmlheight = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
            var windowheight = window.innerHeight;  
            if ( htmlheight < windowheight ) { 
                document.body.height = windowheight;
                if ( windowheight>t2) {
                    tb.sheight=(windowheight-t2);
                }
                else {
                    tb.sheight=10;
                }
            } 
            else { 
                document.body.height = htmlheight;
                if ( htmlheight>t2) {
                    tb.sheight= (htmlheight-t2-50);
                }
                else {
                    tb.sheight= 10;
                }
            } 
        }
        tb.swidth=td.width;
        if(!tb.swidth || tb.swidth.length==0) {
            tb.swidth=td.style.width;
            if(!tb.swidth) tb.swidth = '100%';
            if(tb.swidth.indexOf('%')==-1) {
                tb.swidth = parseInt(tb.swidth);    
            }
        }
        tb.noOfRows=_noOfRows;
        tb.noOfCols=_noOfCols;
        addScrollerDivs(_tid,_noOfCols);
        tbl[tbl.length]=tb;
        //reInit();
    };
})();
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var tableDone = false;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function resizeListTable0() {
    if ( navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ) {
        resizeListTable(false);
    }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function getPX(x){ x2=''+x; return x2.replace(/px/, ''); } 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function resizeListTable(forceNewTable) {

    if ( navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ) {
        var divObjId    = 'ResizableListTableDiv';
        var divObj2Id   = 'ResizableListTableBodyDiv';

        var ResizableListTableDiv       = document.getElementById(divObjId);
        var ResizableListTableBodyDiv   = document.getElementById(divObj2Id);

        if ( ResizableListTableBodyDiv != null ) {

            var divObjHeight    = ResizableListTableDiv.style.height;
            var tableWidth      = ResizableListTableBodyDiv.style.width; 
            var numCols         = ResizableListTable.firstChild.firstChild.childNodes.length;

            var t2=mytop(divObj2Id)+80;
            var l2=myleft(divObj2Id)+40;

            var htmlwidth = document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth;
            var htmlheight = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
            var windowwidth = window.innerWidth;
            var windowheight = window.innerHeight;  

            if (forceNewTable ||  ! tableDone) {
                tableDone = true;
            }

            var d=document;
            var windowwidth = window.innerWidth;
            var windowheight = window.innerHeight;
            if (typeof window.innerWidth!='undefined') {
                windowwidth = window.innerWidth;
                windowheight = window.innerHeight;
            } else {
                 if (d.documentElement &&
                 typeof d.documentElement.clientWidth!='undefined' &&
                 d.documentElement.clientWidth!=0) {
                     windowwidth = d.documentElement.clientWidth;
                     windowheight = d.documentElement.clientHeight;
                 } else {
                     if (d.body &&
                     typeof d.body.clientWidth!='undefined') {
                         windowwidth = d.body.clientWidth;
                         windowheight = d.body.clientHeight;
                     }
                 }
            }


            if ( htmlheight < windowheight ) { 
                document.body.height = windowheight + "px";
                if ( windowheight>t2) {
                    ResizableListTableBodyDiv.style.height = (windowheight-t2) + "px";
                }
                else {
                    ResizableListTableBodyDiv.style.height = "10px";
                }
            } 
            else { 
                document.body.height = htmlheight + "px";
                if ( htmlheight>t2) {
                    ResizableListTableBodyDiv.style.height = (htmlheight-t2) + "px";
                }
                else {
                    ResizableListTableBodyDiv.style.height = "10px";
                }
            } 

            if ( htmlwidth < windowwidth ) { 
                document.body.width = windowwidth + "px";
                ResizableListTableDiv.style.width = (windowwidth-l2) + "px";
                ResizableListTableBodyDiv.style.width = (windowwidth-l2) + "px";
            } 
            else { 
                if ( htmlwidth < l2 ) {
                    l2=0;
                }
                document.body.width = htmlwidth + "px"; 
                ResizableListTableDiv.style.width = (htmlwidth-l2) + "px";
                ResizableListTableBodyDiv.style.width = (htmlwidth-l2) + "px";
            } 


            ResizableListTableBodyDiv.onscroll = function (e) {
                ResizableListTableDiv.scrollLeft = ResizableListTableBodyDiv.scrollLeft;
            };
            ResizableListTableBodyDiv.style.display = 'block';
            ResizableListTableBodyDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';

        }
    }
    return; 
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function mytop(n){ 
   var o=document.getElementById(n),r=o.offsetTop; 
   while(o=o.offsetParent)r+=o.offsetTop; 
   return r; 
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function myleft(n){ 
   var o=document.getElementById(n),r=o.offsetLeft; 
   while(o=o.offsetParent)r+=o.offsetLeft; 
   return r; 
} 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ( navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ) {
    if (window.addEventListener) { //DOM method for binding an event
        window.addEventListener("load", resizeListTable0(), false);
        window.addEventListener("resize", resizeListTable0(), false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) { //IE exclusive method for binding an event
        window.attachEvent("onload", resizeListTable0);
        window.attachEvent("onresize", resizeListTable0);
    }
    else if (document.getElementById) { //support older modern browsers
        window.onload=resizeListTable0();
        window.resize=resizeListTable0();
    }
}
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<span
    style='border: solid 1pt red; margin: 5px 5px 5px 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%; width: 25%; position: relative; float: left; overflow: auto'>
<table border=0 style='width: 100%;'>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello World</td></tr>
    </table>
</span>


<span style='width: 100%; border: blue solid 1pt '> 
<hr>
<span id='ResizableListTableDiv'
    style='border: solid 1pt green; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 55%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; height: 100%;'>
</span> 
<span id='ResizableListTableBodyDiv'
    style='border: solid 1pt orange; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 95%; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; height: 90%;'>

<table width=1400 id='ResizableListTable' style='padding:0px; margin:0px; border: none;'>
    <tr><th width=100>Column 1</th><th width=400>Column 2</th><th width=200>Column 3</th><th width=400>Column 4</th><th width=300>Column 5</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td><td>Column 4</td><td>Column 5</td></tr>
</table>
</span>
</span>
</body>
```

Comment: I would definitely recommend jQuery, your JavaScript is really hard to understand in its current form. With jQuery you might have 20% of the lines of code you have at the moment.

Comment: You might want to remove the `width=1400` from the `ResizableListTable` table.

Comment: removing the line doesn't seem to make a difference (zooming in and out showing the problem straight away).... and jQuery not an option here. :-(

Comment: Yah!... think I've fixed it ... add "overflow-x: auto" to the blue span ("<span style='width: 100%; border: blue solid 1pt; overflow-x: auto'>  ").